# Using dotcloud and vagrant together

Tags: vagrant, dotcloud

Has anyone thought about using dotcloud and vagrant together?  It would be super sweet to be able to type "vagrant up" into a dotcloud application and have vagrant read from the dotcloud.yml file and create an local environment that would mirror what it would look like if you did a "dotcloud push".

I have a semi-working version, but it isn't automatic.  You just create both the dotcloud.yml and Vagrantfile in the same folder and have slightly different setup scripts.

Comment: If you contact support@dotcloud.com and refer to this SO post, we might have something that can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the nearest thing you could use would be http://docker.io

Comment: Now that [next.dotCloud.com is moving to use buildpacks](https://next.dotcloud.com/dev-center/guides/third-party-buildpacks/third-party-buildpacks), you should be able to use local buildpack development environments ([Mason](https://github.com/ddollar/mason) seems to be deprecated, but there are others like [Buildstep](https://github.com/progrium/buildstep) that you could use).